# React Native router flux Router Scene Background image

Tags: react-native, redux-router

Is there any way to set the background image for the React native redux router flux scene.

```
<Router getSceneStyle={() => ({ backgroundColor: 'transparent' })}>
        <Scene>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true} initial={!this.props.isLoggedIn}>
                <Scene key="login" component={Login} initial={true} />
                <Scene key="signup" component={Signup} title="Register" />
       </Scene>
       <Scene  key="app" hideNavBar={true} initial={this.props.isLoggedIn}>
                <Scene key="home" component={Home} />
       </Scene>
```

I have search but didn't found any solution to set the background image for the redux router flux any help will be appreciated

THanks in advance

Comment: is this from `react-native-router-flux`? it is because `getSceneStyle` isnt listed as a prop for `<Router />`, but `sceneStyle` is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is just an example actually i am trying to put background image for all the scene not the background color but unable to find a way to use background images for route or scene.Thanks

Comment: i think you completely misinterpret my earlier comment. haha. i'm trying to replicate your example on my end but i can't locate the `<Scene />` component under the `redux-router` library. perhaps, someone else can take it from here.